# When I new add java file or open java file, how can I set the default open state is checked the 'User Soft Wraps'?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: image description here]

This is my IntelliJ IDEA, a java file is open, you can see in the upper snapshot, but I want when I open the java file, the User Soft Wraps default is be checked, where I can set the option?

Comment: what version are you using? On 2016.3.4 on Mac OS I also have the option 'Soft-Wrap All Files'

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2, on Windows .

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set it in preferences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>S</kbd> or `File -> Settingg` to goto the Settings panel, then check the `Eidtor->General -> Soft Wraps`: Use soft wraps in editor.

[image]

Then it will default use User Soft Wraps in your IntelliJ IDEA.